# Texture that only visible in shadows

Tags: texturing, shaders, masking

I am trying to shade an earth model. Trying to show night lights on the dark side, but I am having hard time on figuring out how to use light path node, to isolate night emission at the sunshine. I can semi-manually mask it with normal vector node, which gives me an gizmo I could rotate to align with incoming light. It is inconvenient that way and I need help if there is a more practical way to achieve desired results.

Comment: Show us your node set-up, images of the result etc.

Comment: It is pretty straight forward actually, a mix shader has one daylight node group plugged on one socket and night group is plugged to the other one. I just cannot figure out what to plug to the factor input.